# Proper way to programmatically set Transform Origin

Tags: javascript, transform

Is this the proper way to programmatically set the transform origin, cross-browser? Thanks

```
var s = element.style;

s.webkitTransformOrigin = transform;
   s.MozTransformOrigin = transform;      //cap first letter
    s.msTransformOrigin = transform;
     s.OTransformOrigin = transform;      //cap first letter
      s.transformOrigin = transform;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to do it like this using Modernizr:

```
transform: null,
transformOrigin: null,

initCss: function() {
    this.transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform');
    this.transformOrigin = Modernizr.prefixed('transformOrigin');
},

setTransform: function(element, transform) {
    if (this.transform) {
        element.style[this.transform] = transform;
    }
    else {                                //fallback just in case
        var s = element.style;

        s.webkitTransform = transform;
        s.MozTransform = transform;       //cap first letter
        s.msTransform = transform;
        s.OTransform = transform;         //cap first letter
        s.transform = transform;
    }
},
```

Thoughts?